# How do I make the "Create an account" form as the default view from this codepen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not really sure what par to the CSS is displaying the the "sign in form" first instead of the "create and account form"

Is it the z-index of the .form class?

```
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
```

Codepen link: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/rxddKy)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/7gtcmbjz/

You should just change css

```
.form .register-form {
      display: none;
    }
```

to

```
.form .login-form {
  display: none;
}
```